# Pygame proble, moving picture

Tags: python, pygame

Thats my problem on the Picture...The stripes

[image: My Problem]
How can i fix that?

My Code:

import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('start.wav')
sound.play()

size = width, height = 1600, 848
speed = [2, 2]
black = (0, 0, 0)

pygame.mouse.set_cursor(*pygame.cursors.broken_x)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
background = pygame.image.load("background.PNG")
dragon1 = pygame.image.load("dragon1.gif")
screen.blit(background, (0,0))

x,y=0,0
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
speed=250
movex, movey=0,0

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    if event.type==KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_a:
                movex=-1
            elif event.key==K_d:
                movex=+1
            elif event.key==K_w:
                movey=-1
            elif event.key==K_s:
                movey=+1
    if event.type==KEYUP:
            if event.key==K_a:
                movex=0
            elif event.key==K_d:
                movex=0
            elif event.key==K_w:
                movey=0
            elif event.key==K_s:
                movey=0
    x+=movex
    y+=movey

```
screen.blit(dragon1, (x,y))
pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to blit the background image at each update or loop in your mainloop like so:

```
while True:
    #mainloop stuff
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    screen.blit(dragon1, (x,y))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

The way you are currently doing it you are only blitting the BG once then you are blitting the dragon but the screen isnt being refreshed so you keep seeing each place the dragon was blitted at before

Comment: Thx! :) that works. but now the dragon is realy slow...

Comment: and another problem is, when i press two keys together, the dragon moves without stop...